# Escaping single quote inside a variable before database update

Tags: mysql, perl

This might be a very basic question.

I have a variable $name which is input through a form from html page.
Now i have to update value of this $name into the database table using a sql query.

When $name has single quotes in it, the database update fails. Eg. James O'Hara
when it does not have single quotes, the update works fine.

Is there a way to escape this single quote inside a variable before updating the database.?
I dont want to strip the single quote. just want to escape it so the update goes through fine and actual name is updated in the database.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the best approach to this is to prepare a query and use a placeholder. Then pass the data to the database to populate the prepared query.

An ORM such as [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) will do this for you automatically.

If you are using DBI directly then you would do [something like this](http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
foreach my $email (@emails) {
    $sth->execute($email);
    $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Placeholders have the added benefit of protecting that query from SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the provided quoting functions

```
$dbh->do("
    UPDATE `MyTable`
       SET `MyField` = ".$dbh->quote($my_value)."
     WHERE `id` = ".$dbh->quote($id)."
");
```

or use placeholders

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    UPDATE `MyTable`
       SET `MyField` = ?
     WHERE `id` = ?
");

$sth->execute($my_value, $id);
```

The latter is prettier, but under some circumstances, the former can be faster (since the DB can optimized the query better knowing the type of the expressions in advance).